# Migrate a subdag to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a subdag and want to migrate it to GCP

```
# dags/wh_qvl_hourly_spark_subdag.py
from pathlib import Path

from airflow.models import DAG, Param
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

from lib.template import QTemplate
from mysql_plugin.operators.mysql_operator import WarehouseMySqlMultiOperator
from spark_plugin import WarehouseSparkOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql import MySqlHook
from datetime import datetime
import time, logging


# Dag is returned by a factory method
def subdag_alisegmentcore(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, default_args, start_date, schedule_interval):
    dag = DAG(
        '%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        start_date=start_date,
        default_args=default_args
    )

    ali_pre_load_spark = WarehouseSparkOperator(
        task_id='alisegmentcore_pre_load_spark',
        processor_name='AliSegmentCorePreloadSparkProcessor',
        job_type='hourly',
        dag=dag
    )

    dim_ali_adnet_segment_spark = WarehouseSparkOperator(
        task_id='dim_ali_adnet_segment_spark',
        processor_name='DimAliAdnetSegmentProcessor',
        default_spark_configs={"spark.speculation": "false"},
        job_type='hourly',
        dag=dag
    )

    dim_ali_adnet_segment_group_relation_spark = WarehouseSparkOperator(
        task_id='dim_ali_adnet_segment_group_relation_spark',
        processor_name='DimAdnetSegmentGroupRelationProcessor',
        default_spark_configs={"spark.speculation": "false"},
        job_type='hourly',
        dag=dag
    )

    ali_segment_core_spark = WarehouseSparkOperator(
        task_id='ali_segment_core_spark',
        processor_name='AliSegmentCoreProcessor',
        job_type='hourly',
        dag=dag
    )

    process_params = {"start_time": Param(datetime.now())}

    FULL_EXECUTION_DATE_DATETIME = QTemplate.FULL_EXECUTION_DATE_DATETIME

    call_spLoadDimOtpAdnetSegment = WarehouseMySqlMultiOperator(
        task_id='call_spLoadDimOtpAdnetSegment',
        sql=f"call spLoadDimOtpAdnetSegment('{FULL_EXECUTION_DATE_DATETIME}'); ",
        script_name='spLoadDimOtpAdnetSegment',
        dag=dag,
        params=process_params
    )

    # Query to check if any instance of adnet_conversion_retarg_receipts/campaign_conversion_receipts is running
    query_chk_acrr_ccr_state = """SELECT run_id FROM task_instance WHERE dag_id in ('wh_metasegment_audience_conversion_hourly', 'wh_qvl_hourly_spark')
                         AND task_id IN ('build_adnet_conversion_retarg_receipts','campaign_conversion_receipts_spark') AND (state = 'running' OR state = 'up_for_retry');"""

    def wait_acrr_ccr_completion():
        mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='wh_airflow_db')
        result_set = mysql_hook.get_records(query_chk_acrr_ccr_state)
        while result_set:
            logging.info('Select Queries on ali_segment_core running for {}'.format(result_set[0][0]))
            time.sleep(60)
            result_set = mysql_hook.get_records(query_chk_acrr_ccr_state)
        logging.info('Sqoop Import To Hive ali_segment_core')

    # wait for ali_segment_core from any hour to end to proceed with adnet_conversion_retarg_receipts
    wait_for_alisegmentcore_queries = PythonOperator(
        task_id='wait_for_alisegmentcore_queries',
        python_callable=wait_acrr_ccr_completion,
        dag=dag
    )

    start_downstream = DummyOperator(
        task_id="start_downstream",
        dag=dag
    )

    ali_pre_load_spark >> dim_ali_adnet_segment_spark >> start_downstream
    ali_pre_load_spark >> dim_ali_adnet_segment_group_relation_spark >> start_downstream

    start_downstream >> call_spLoadDimOtpAdnetSegment
    start_downstream >> wait_for_alisegmentcore_queries >> ali_segment_core_spark

    return dag
```